# rendering a custom form helper (ckeditor_rails) in an activeadmin form:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, activeadmin

I've got two gems that i use and enjoy

gem 'activeadmin'
and
gem "ckeditor"

I'd like for my 'content' field to use ckeditor.

In my past apps, I render ckeditor in a form like this:

```
<%= form_for @resource do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :content %>
     <br />
     <%= cktext_area_tag("page_part[content]", @page_part.content) %>
  </div>
...
<% end %>
```

Now i just added activeadmin to my stack and like what i see so far. So, I read that you can customize the form like so by editing the app/admin/#{resource}.rb file:

```
  ActiveAdmin.register NewsItem do
    form :html => { :enctype => "multipart/form-data" } do |f| 
      f.inputs "NewsItem", :multipart => true do
      f.input :title
      f.input :content
      f.input :photo
      #NOT WORKING 
      cktext_area_tag("news_item[content]", @news_item.content)
      #NOT WORKING
     end 
     f.buttons
   end 
 end
```

How can i get this form helper to work in active_admin, and what would i put in place of @news_item.content. @news_item is null... So right now I'm a bit confused.

When I try even witout reference to @news_item like so:

```
  cktext_area_tag("news_item[content]", 'i cant be edited properly')
```

I still get:

```
  undefined method `cktext_area_tag' for #<ActiveAdmin::DSL:0x00000007e02250>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok,

Answer was pretty simple.

Taken from active admin's own documentation page: http://activeadmin.info/docs/5-forms.html

```
 ActiveAdmin.register Post do
   form :partial => "form"
 end
```

Then I was able to use any form helper tags I wanted to:

```
  <%= javascript_include_tag "/javascripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js" %>
     <%= semantic_form_for [:admin, @news_item], :multipart => true do |f| %>
     <%= f.inputs :title, :photo %>
     <%= cktext_area_tag("news_item[content]", @news_item.content) %>
  <% end  %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
f.template.some_view_method
```